# encrypted object serialization on android, cannot load from file

Tags: java, android, file, serialization, loading

First. Never posted on here before, sorry if I break any rules!

I am trying to make an app for android that serializes a sealed object of a class that contains an array of files (sorta like an encrypted volume).

I have managed to create the file, but for some reason cannot load data from it. Not sure how android serialization differs from regular desktop apps, and every time I google how to do it, I get links to posts from several years ago.

On application startup, I run a check is the file exist, if not, then create it. Note: this part is very sketchy as it was meant for quickly testing the app itself, will change it in the future. This is what it looks like:

```
if (!Files.exists(Paths.get("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/vault.vlt")))
```

To create the file:

```
    final Cipher cipher = generateCipher();

    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("vault.vlt",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    final CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher);
    final ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);

    objectOutputStream.writeObject(Core.getVault());
    objectOutputStream.close();

    Toast.makeText(this,"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To load the file:

```
    final Cipher cipher = generateCipher();

    final FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("vault.vlt");
    final CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);
    final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);

    Core.setVault((Vault) objectInputStream.readObject());
    objectInputStream.close();

    Toast.makeText(this,Core.getVault().apples,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And this is what my generate cipher method looks like using Guava:

```
    // key size
    final byte keySize = 32; // 256

    // Hashing
    final String hash =
            Hashing.sha256()
                    .hashString(Core.getVault().getPassword(), Charsets.UTF_8)
                    .toString().substring(0, keySize);

    // Creating keys
    final byte[] key = hash.getBytes();
    final String transformation = "AES";
    final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, transformation);

    // Creating cipher
    @SuppressLint("GetInstance") final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    return cipher;
```

And here is a stacktrace of my error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 02FD0D3D
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:302)
        at theredspy15.vault115.EntranceActivity.loadVault(EntranceActivity.java:70)
        at theredspy15.vault115.EntranceActivity.enter(EntranceActivity.java:41)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `Cipher` into `DECRYPT_MODE` when reading from the file.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I am still having trouble detecting the file. is there a better way, compared to my check shown above (if statement at the top)? As the openFileOutput method, only needs a name in the parameters.

Comment: Just try to open it and deal with the `FileNotFoundException` when and if it arises. Don't try to predict the future.